# Saving RAM when writing log files

Tags: java, io, filewriter

I'm having RAM issues when I launch my Java program on a server. I think that the problem is due to the fact that I'm writing log files, which can be quite large (over 100MB). I'm looking for an efficient way to do that and I'm confused with the different options available.

After having a look at the [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html), I've seen that *flushing* the stream could be helpful, but I'm not sure which of the different classes I should go for. I'm currently using the [PrintWriter class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) which is causing the RAM issue and I'm looking for the best alternative.

I have a question about flushing the stream. From what I understood, the strings are appended to a stream, and then flushed after a *print* method is called or when the cache memory is exceeded. Since I'm writing log files, I don't think it's a good solution because if the program crashes at some point, I would like to know what was its last status. Am I correct?

I can see that the *PrintSteam* class has a constructor that requires a *Writer* and a boolean telling whether *autoflush* should be activated or not. The [FileWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html) class (inheriting from Writer) also has a *Write* and a *flush* method, so I'm confused. What happens when I create a *FileWriter*, pass it to a *PrintSteam*, and set *autoflush* to *true* on the *PrintStream*? Is the *autoflush* really active, I mean would it implicitly call the *flush* method of the *FileWriter*?

Finally, what is the class I should go for to write my log files? Again, my priority is to save RAM and be able to track crashes/errors easily. Should I go for an non-buffer approach.

Thanks

EDIT : Here's what my code looks like :

```
output = new PrintWriter(filename, "utf-8");
output.println("Some info");
```

Comment: You need to use a profiler to be *sure* that the problem is because you're logging. I cannot imagine that logging is the real problem unless you're using some kind of asynchronous logging which keeps the logs in memory.

Comment: @Augusto I found out that when the program is killed by the system, the log file is not present, which makes me think that it is generated at the end of the execution, or after a while. Plus, the program does the same things over and over in a loop and it's only after like half an hour that it's killed. The only thing that changes is the size of the logged data, because the same instructions are repeated. What do you think?

Comment: Unless something crazy is done (e.g. a huge buffer) writing to a file does not cause a memory problem.

Comment: Can you shows us the problematic piece of code?

Comment: @SlavaImeshev I'm updating my post.

Comment: Yeah, this shouldn't cause problems it it's called once..  Questions: a) What happens to the variable 'output' once you are done writing logs? Are you closing it properly? b) Is this piece of code called from multiple threads?

Comment: @SlavaImeshev a) Nothing, I'm not closing it. Do you think that's why? A new file is created every time the program is launched though. b) The second line is used in many methods/loops.

Comment: Yes, it's quite possible that eventually you will run out of memory if you are calling 'new PrintWriter(filename, "utf-8");' repeatedly. By the way, if you just need to log debug/info/warnings, there are already APIs that work great, Log4j for instance.

Comment: @SlavaImeshev Only the second line is called repeatedly ( output.println("Some info") ). Could this be the cause?

Answer (score 1):

> > I don't think it's a good solution because if the program crashes at some point, I would like to know what was its last status. Am I correct?

Kind of - uncaught exceptions will end up in the standard error stream of your process (in linux), so you will probably get some stuff. Hopefully you are catching exceptions and making sure your logs flush in those cases. So, if you are careful with this approach you can get all the information.

> > Is the autoflush really active, I mean would it implicitly call the flush method of the FileWriter?

I believe so - flush causes java to write the buffer out to disk. If you provide the result of experiments and maybe some data from jprofiler or another heap analysis tool, it will be easier to help.

> > Finally, what is the class I should go for to write my log files?

There will always be a buffer between RAM and disk. This basic approach you are describing should be able to write arbitrary amount of logs to disk, provided you are careful about flushing buffers and closing the writers before exit.

That being said, it's rarely good to refine such a low level approach for a pretty common problem. I'd start by looking through the java.util.logging package. Some people go so far as to use aspect oriented programming based inject for logging. Logging can be a complicated part of a distributed system with low latency requirements.